# How do we handle alter table column datatypes in Cassandra, in actual scenarios?

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I'm aware of the restrictions Cassandra has on modifying column data types once table is created or even dropping and adding column with same name of different data type.
Dropping and Adding is allowed with [restrictions](https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cql_data_types_c.html#cql_data_types_c__cql_data_type_compatibility).

But, if we talk about actual scenarios, it's not that uncommon to modify table schema during initial phase of our project.
**Example:** modifying `Name column of User table from TEXT to a UDT(User Defined Type)` that could encapsulate more information.

Coming from a RDBMS background, this is a very strange behaviour and maybe someone with actual project experience on Cassandra can answer it.

How do we handle such scenario of modifying column datatypes ? And what are the best practices.
Also, is this a common behaviour with other NoSQL or columnar databases ?

Comment: A friendly reminder that Stack Overflow is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems. For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. If you post it there, I'd be happy to help. Cheers!

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/314933/how-do-we-handle-alter-table-column-datatypes-in-cassandra-in-actual-scenarios

Comment: @ErickRamirez waiting for a reply.

Comment: Apologies as I got sidetracked. I've responded to you on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/314933/. Cheers!